# How do I compare upper 40 bits in two longs

Tags: java, bit-shift, bit, endianness

I have a long value identifying invalid input and it should include 0s in upper 40 bits. So everytime I get a new input I've to compare it's upper 40 bits to verify if those are 0's to make sure it isn't invalid.

```
long invalid_id = 0;
long input ; //some input 

if ((input << 24) == id) {
   // invalid
}
```

Will this be sufficient?

Comment: Do you mean to put "long invalid_id = 0;" ? The space between "invalid" and "id" will probably cause an error.

Comment: You're on the right track, but ... Try to envision that your integer is written (on paper) as a binary number of 64 1's and 0's.  The left 40 bits are the upper bits that you want to compare.  When you use `<<`, this shifts everything to the *left* (with new 0's appearing at the right), and some of those upper bits will fall off the paper.

Comment: Also, if `invalid_id` is a constant that will always be the same throughout your program, best to make it `static final`; also you might want to make `INVALID_ID` upper case since that's the usual convention for constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to be using the right shift operators (there are two) and shift thevalue **right**:

```
if ((input >>> 24) == 0) {
    // high-order 40 bits are all 0.
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply bit-mask with:

```
if ((input & 0xFFFFFFFFFF000000L) == 0) {
    // high-order 40 bits are all 0.
}
```

Note that `>>>` will put 0 in the high-order bits, and `>>` will put 0 for positive numbers, and 1 for negative.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the top 40 bits are the same in two long values

```
long a, b;
if (((a ^ b) >>> 24) == 0) // top 40 bits are the same.
```

or

```
if (((a ^ b) & 0xFFFFFFFFFF00000000L) == 0)
```